Azure AD B2C - Split Email Verification and set Password into Two screens
I would like to split the signup process into phases, But for that I need to somehow subscribe to the verification request and then according to the result I want to show the next phase (or present the error if not verified)
Is there anyway to achieve this?

Yes, this is possible using a Custom Policy. You need to split Email Verification to a separate Orchestration step, and add a ClaimsProvider for it. You also need to set up a ClaimsProvider for Local Account Signup using a read only email.
Luckily, there is a comprehensive sample library for Azure AD B2C custom policies, in which this particular case is also present. See Azure AD B2C Samples GitHub Repository here.
In case the link goes sour, here is a full example policy for this. This code is courtesy of https://github.com/yoelhor and other possible contributors:
    <TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" 
  TenantId="yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com" 
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_Demo_SignUp_SignIn_SplitEmailVerificationAndSignUp" 
  PublicPolicyUri="http://yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_Demo_SignUp_SignIn_SplitEmailVerificationAndSignUp">
  
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>

  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <!-- Read only email address to present to the user-->
      <ClaimType Id="readonlyEmail">
        <DisplayName>E-mail Address</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readonlyEmail" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>

    <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccount.emailVerification">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.8</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
        </Metadata>
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.localaccount.emailVerification.en" />
        </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>

    <Localization Enabled="true">
      <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
        <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
      </SupportedLanguages>
      <LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccount.emailVerification.en">
        <LocalizedStrings>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="button_continue">Continue</LocalizedString>
        </LocalizedStrings>
      </LocalizedResources>
    </Localization>
  </BuildingBlocks>

  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Email Verification</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <!--Email verification only-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="EmailVerification">
          <DisplayName>Initiate Email Address Verification For Local Account</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccount.emailVerification</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <!--Sign-up self-asserted technical profile without Email verification-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
            <!-- Remove sign-up email verification -->
            <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">False</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <!--Sample: Set input the ReadOnlyEmail claim type to prefilled the email address-->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <!-- Sample: Display the ReadOnlyEmail claim type (instead of email claim type)-->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <!-- Sample: Disable session management for sign-up page -->
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn_Custom">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange_EmailVerification" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerification" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange_WithReadOnlyEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>

  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn_Custom" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>

